# How to temporarily disable frameworks added through POD file in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm using cocoapods in xcode for few frameworks (Firebase extensions, fabric, facebook sdk etc). The moment I generated the workspace, it take too long to compile and makes it very difficult to work on the project.

I'm looking for a solution where I can temporarily disable the frameworks that are added through pod.

I have been trying few ideas but all of them have their drawbacks.

1) Remove the pods and update the repo (but it has to download all the pods again)

2) Make a backup of pod folder and create a temporary pod file with very limited frameworks (Pod always try to download the selected frameworks even if they're present in the folder)

3) Remove the frameworks from dependencies (This still compile the frameworks as they're added as a separate project in the workspace)

Comment: You could create a separate target and specify a minimal setup for this target in your pod file, then conditionally include code for these pods... but is it really worth it? I mean, compilation time for external modules should be minimal after the first build and while code in them is unchanged...

Comment: https://github.com/leavez/cocoapods-binary might help